# Converting Timestamp to UTC pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, utc

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format.
The Timestamp values are in DateTime format (GMT Time)
I want to add a new column to the dataframe with the UTC values related to each Timestamp.

How can I do this in pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2', '3'],
                     'TimeStamp': [2022-12-19 22:56:24, 2022-12-19 22:57:46, 2022-12-19 22:59:08]})
```

I tried the below code, but it gives me an error.

```
df['x'] = dt.datetime(df['TimeStamp']).timestamp()

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Desired Output:

| ID | TimeStamp | UTC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-19 22:56:24 | 1671490584 |
| 2 | 2022-12-19 22:57:46 | 1671490666 |
| 3 | 2022-12-19 22:59:08 | 1671490748 |

Comment: Yes option 3 of that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df["UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TimeStamp"]).map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp).astype(int)
print(df)

  ID           TimeStamp         UTC
0  1 2022-12-19 22:56:24  1671490584
1  2 2022-12-19 22:57:46  1671490666
2  3 2022-12-19 22:59:08  1671490748
```